# PostgreSQL Multiple recordset in function

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am a newbie in postgresql and trying to use following function from this link [PostgreSQL Cursor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#plpgsql-cursor-for-loop)

```
CREATE FUNCTION myfunc(refcursor, refcursor) RETURNS SETOF refcursor AS $$
    BEGIN
        OPEN $1 FOR SELECT * FROM table_1;
        RETURN NEXT $1;
        OPEN $2 FOR SELECT * FROM table_2;
        RETURN NEXT $2;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then when i tried to run the function in pgAdmin4

```
-- need to be in a transaction to use cursors.
    BEGIN;

    SELECT * FROM myfunc('a', 'b');

    FETCH ALL FROM a;
    FETCH ALL FROM b;
    COMMIT;
```

I only get `Query returned successfully in 133 msec.`
NO table data are shown . 
Need help to see my data . 
Thank you in advance !!!

Comment: Not sure what you want to do or if you can return cursors as result. But if your function return cursors, you aren't saving it those anywhere.

Comment: It's possible that you can see results of the last command only in some GUI tools like PgAdmin. Try to execute the transaction in [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html), you will see all the results.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza is there any way i can see the the table in pgAdmin ?